# Modify parameter of method by value in annotation aspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I started learing aspectJ and I wondering is it possible to create aspect in file .aj instead of annotation in .java, this is my example:

I have this aspect which modify value of parameter in method

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Te)")
public Object setupParam(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    Te myAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Te.class);
    if (args != null) 
        args[0] = (int) args[0] * myAnnotation.w();
    return pjp.proceed(args);
}
```

and I don't know how to create this asspect in .aj file, is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible.

```
public aspect MyAspect {

    public MyAspect() {
      System.out.println("Aspect instance created");
    }

   pointcut myPointcut(ParameterType parameter)
               : ("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(Te));

    Object around(ParameterType parameter) : myPointcut(parameter) {
       // Business logic here
       // 'thisJoinPointStaticPart' will give you access to join point
       // 'this' will give you access to advice instance itself
       // `return proceed();` will allow you to execute advised join point
    }
}
```

I would suggest to use [Eclipse AspectJ Developer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/), which provides many useful features, like intellisence autocomplete, javadocs and aspect visualization and etc. This might help you to learn faster.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I use STS 3.9.1 and aspectJ is default.. I little don't understand part with ParameterType, could you explain me more specifically?

Comment: Welcome. ParameterType means any Java Type - for example java.lang.String or java.lang.Object - those parameters match arguments of advised method - thus you are getting access to parameters of advised method and you can access those objects in your around advice. For example you are advising (intercepting) method with parameter of java.lang.String - you advice in Aspectj declares and accesses the same parameter type.